# Woocommerce add to cart settings quantity not showing above 9

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, divi

I have a web site https://westalabamabeecompany.com/ - when I add more than 9 items in the quantity box you can only see one digit - for example, it I have a quantity of 20, you can only see the 2 - not 20. I am using Divi from Elegant Themes and when I edit the Woocommerce Add to Cart Settings, I have tried to edit the margins and padding to no avail. I need to know how to edit the quantity field so you could see 3 or 4 digits.
Thank you.

Comment: Questions on SO must be self-contained. The goal of SO is to create a repository of questions and answers which are valuable to future visitors, not just the person asking the question. Questions which require information from off-site/off-page resources are useless once those resources change or go dead. Any questions where such a resource is required to understand the question should be closed. A [link to a website](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/11987538) might be beneficial in addition to information (e.g. code) in the question itself.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because your CSS in the quantity class.
Your width is 4.3em. Just Change it to 5em.

```
.woocommerce .quantity input.qty {
  width: 5em;
}
```

This is how it looks before

[image]

This is how it looks now.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. When I put this code into the CSS I get this: .woocommerce .quantity input.qty { Expected RBRACE
  width: 5em;
} Unexpected Token '}' - will you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Unexpected token? Are you puting the code in the right place? Css file or theme options for custom css? It work for me and i test it in your site (front end). Please provide more info to give a proper answer.

Comment: I put the code you gave me into the Additional CSS and it worked.